# How to parse child elements from tweepy class

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have written code to parse tweet JSON. I want to use media content and non-media content seperately. Issue is media content is present in few tweets only, and I dont understand how to segregate media and non-media content.

```
for tweet in tweets:
            #pdb.set_trace()
            #if tweet.entities.media:
            twitterData.append({"id": tweet.id,"entities":tweet.entities,"text":tweet.text,"user":tweet.user.name,"img":tweet.user.profile_image_url,"retweet_count":tweet.retweet_count,"source":tweet.source,"source_url":tweet.source_url,"created_at":tweet.created_at,"media_image_url":tweet.entities.media.media_url })
```

This code works, but I am confused now how to parse those tweets which contains media

I tried this way,

```
for tweet in tweets:
        #pdb.set_trace()
        if tweet.entities.media:
            twitterData.append({"id": tweet.id,"entities":tweet.entities,"text":tweet.text,"user":tweet.user.name,"img":tweet.user.profile_image_url,"retweet_count":tweet.retweet_count,"source":tweet.source,"source_url":tweet.source_url,"created_at":tweet.created_at,"media_image_url":tweet.entities.media.media_url })
```

but it gives error

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'media'
```

Which is right, because all tweets does not contain media attribute.

Can someone please help me to write logic here. So that I can access media tweets and non media tweets separately ?

JSON response is like this:

https://justpaste.it/55roi

*Note: had to paste outside of SO because of size and URL shortener restrictions, which are part of the JSON object.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasattr`, like this:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    #pdb.set_trace()
    if hasattr(status.entities, 'media'):
    #if tweet.entities.media:
        twitterData.append({"id": tweet.id,"entities":tweet.entities,"text":tweet.text,"user":tweet.user.name,"img":tweet.user.profile_image_url,"retweet_count":tweet.retweet_count,"source":tweet.source,"source_url":tweet.source_url,"created_at":tweet.created_at,"media_image_url":tweet.entities.media.media_url })
```

That will return `False` if the `media` attribute is missing.